# How do I search for a string and return the string's neighbor word from a text in google apps script?

Tags: text, google-apps-script, gmail, find, google-sheets

I'm getting some spesific emails from gmail to a spreadsheet. But before I send them to spreadsheet. I want to get some spesific data from email plain text. 
For example, there is a word "arrival" in the text and the date next to it. I want to get this date.

This is what I have so far:

```
    function abepostalar() {

 var threads = GmailApp.search('label:AOOA');
  Logger.log(threads);
  Logger.log(threads[0].getMessages());
  Logger.log(threads[0].getMessages().length);
  var messages;// = threads[0].getMessages();
  var ContentEmail;// = messages[0].getBody();


  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    messages = threads[i].getMessages()
    ContentEmail = messages[0].getPlainBody();

    // These are what I tried to find the word. not working.
    //var bilgi = ContentEmail.findText("Uygar");
    //var yazi = ContentEmail.asText().getText();
    //Logger.log(bilgi);


    //MesajlariDosyayaYaz(date); // a function to send date to the spreadsheet
  }
```

}

I tried some other functions [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/container-element) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text?hl=en) couldn't nail it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you get from `messages[0].getPlainBody()` is a string and it appears that you are trying [document service methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/container-element) which of course won't work. Try using [javascript strings methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) instead.

Comment: As you said, I tried js string methods with regex. It works good for me.